# How to update a field of all documents in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to do the equivalent of

```
UPDATE TABLENAME SET COLUMN = COLUMN * 0.725
```

in mongodb.

Here is what I tried but doesn't seem to work. Help!

```
db.costs.update(
  {$mul: {totalcost: NumberDecimal("0.725")}},
  {multi: true}
);
```

generates

> "errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: $mul"

and the below

```
db.costs.update(
  { recordId: {$regex:"*"}},
  {$mul: {totalcost: NumberDecimal("0.725")}},
  {multi: true}
);
```

generates

> "errmsg" : "Regular expression is invalid: nothing to repeat"

Apparently I'm missing the syntax and scoured through the documentation but couldn't find anything that could help.

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in regex here?

Comment: Trying to find the equivalent of UPDATE TABLENAME SET COLUMN = COLUMN * 0.725

Comment: In mongo, you cannot pass the same field in where and update sections. Specify a different field. In your second query, you have mentioned 'recordId', which is correct, but the regex pattern is not correct. What exactly are you trying to filter in your regex?

Comment: Not trying to filter , but match all documents in the collection and update a field in each document

Comment: Then your query should be like:    db.costs.update( { },
  {$mul: {totalcost: NumberDecimal("0.725")}},
  {multi: true}
);

Comment: @Anban. Thanks for your response. Its interesting your version of the query updates all the records in the collection, Yet the one provided by Mr.S.Sharma leaves out some records. Wondering what could be the difference.

Comment: { "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 7365, "modifiedCount" : 7230 } - this is the result from running Mr.S.Sharma's query and the below is the result from your query: 
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 7365, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 7365 })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
{
    $mul:{
        "totalCost": 0.725
    }
})
```

**Data set:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d882f0d38db7cf8d3f75cdd"), "totalCost" : 1000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d882f0d38db7cf8d3f75cde"), "totalCost" : 1200 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d882f0d38db7cf8d3f75cdf"), "totalCost" : 1500 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d882f0d38db7cf8d3f75ce0"), "totalCost" : 1800 }
```

**Output:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d882f0d38db7cf8d3f75cdd"), "totalCost" : 725 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d882f0d38db7cf8d3f75cde"), "totalCost" : 870 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d882f0d38db7cf8d3f75cdf"), "totalCost" : 1087.5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d882f0d38db7cf8d3f75ce0"), "totalCost" : 1305 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**. Looks like you are trying to do a bulk update.

```
var bulk = db.getCollection('collection-name').initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
bulk.find({}).update({ $mul : {points: 2}}); // will multiply the field by 2
bulk.execute();
```

There is
should work. For more info, check out [unordered](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp/) and [ordered](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp/) operations.

Comment: Thanks, but, how do I use the $mul operator though? 
db.costs.find( {} ).update( {$mul: {totalcost: NumberDecimal("0.725")}} );
2019-09-22T21:25:23.541-0500 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: TypeError: db.costs.find(...).update is not a function :